# How to display Categories as drop-down select in opencart?

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart2.x

I am trying to have two drop-down select for categories and sub categories. i am using the 3 level search logic from product/search.php and product/search.tpl. this template displays categories, subcategories, sub subcategories. But i want it to be like one drop-down select only all categories and other drop-down select only all sub categories( actually in my case subcategories will be same for all categories, only products will be different).

how can i achieve this?

i was successful in one drop-down select only categories, but not able to do it for sub categories

i want all this for a new search on header other than the normal search engine.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
      <select name="category_id" class="form-control">
        <option value="0"><?php echo $text_category; ?></option>
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category_1) { ?>
        <?php if ($category_1['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $category_1['category_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $category_1['name']; ?></option>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $category_1['category_id']; ?>"><?php echo $category_1['name']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
       </select>
    </div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
      <select name="Subcategory_id" class="form-control">
        <option value="0"><?php echo $text_subbcategory; ?></option>
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category_1) { ?>
        <?php foreach ($category_1['children'] as $category_2) { ?>
        <?php if ($category_2['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $category_2['category_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $category_2['name']; ?></option>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $category_2['category_id']; ?>"><?php echo $category_2['name']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: My Question is valid i guess. Please help otherwise for what is missing

Comment: SO is primarily for coding issues. So if the issue is with your code post the code

Comment: You mention you succeeded in one part and failed doing the same with small changes? Show us the code, show us where the errors happen

Comment: Thanks @riggsfolly and AlexD for guidance. does it look good now ?